# Word for "money contributed monthly by a group of people so that each month one collects the total sum"

Tags: word-request

I don't know if this culture exists in English speaking countries, but in my country a group of people would contribute a set sum of money every month so that each one of the group receives the total sum of the group's contributions. This is some kind of a lending system to which people resort so they can use the money collected to get married or buy a car or similar things. Is there a word for this?

Comment: No such custom exists in the US, and we have no word for it, not in the vernacular, at least. Anthropologists probably have a word for it.

Answer (score 7):

This sounds like ***pooling*** to me.

Sometimes people can pool their resources. [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pool) defines the word as:

> **pool** (*v.*) to combine (as resources) in a common pool or effort

whereas [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pool) defines this as:

> **pool** (*n.*) a number of people or a quantity of a particular thing, such as money, collected together for shared use by several people or organizations:
>   *Everybody puts some money into a common pool.*
>   *We need a reserve pool of cash, just to be on the safe side.*

Note: In many English-speaking countries, this usage of *pool* often refers to a gambling pool, where people put money into a "pot" that the winner collects; such pools often are related to sporting events. However, the word could also be used in the way you describe:

> *Let's all pool our money together so that there will be a fund to draw from when one of us has to plan a wedding or a funeral*.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand you correctly, this form of financial scheme is known as:

> **rotating savings and credit association**.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_savings_and_credit_association):

> A **rotating savings and credit association** (**ROSCA**) is a group of individuals who agree to meet for a defined period in order to save and borrow together, a form of combined peer-to-peer banking and peer-to-peer lending.
>
> F.J.A. Bouman described ROSCAs as "the poor man's bank, where money is not idle for long but changes hands rapidly, satisfying both consumption and production needs." They are also known as **tandas** (Latin America), ***partnerhand*** (West Indies), ***cundinas*** (Mexico), ***'Hagbad (Somaliland)'susu*** (West Africa and the Caribbean), ***hui*** (Asia), ***Game'ya*** (Middle East), ***kye*** (계) (South Korea), ***tanomosiko*** (頼母子講) (Japan), ***pandeiros*** (Brazil), ***juntas*** (Peru), or ***quiniela***.

Answer (score 6):

The most common term for this sort of thing is **savings pool** or **money pool**.  Examples:

> [Money pools: a centuries-old savings tool reinvented](http://www.csmonitor.com/World/Making-a-difference/Change-Agent/2014/0221/Money-pools-a-centuries-old-savings-tool-reinvented)
>
> [Among the local resilience initiatives being taken are green dollars, timebanks and now savings pools.](http://neweconomics.net.nz/index.php/tag/savings-pools/)

Answer (score 1):

In India, I have heard this called a 'chit fund' and it is considered an example of a 'cooperative lending society'.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chit_fund) quoting Indian legislation:

> A transaction ... under which a person enters into an agreement with a specified number of persons that every one of them shall subscribe a certain sum of money (or a certain quantity of grain instead) by way of periodical installments over a definite period and that each such subscriber shall, in his turn, ... be entitled to the prize amount.

From the [Oxford online dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chit_fund), close to the above definition:

> An institution which accepts savings at interest and lends money for house and other purchases

Answer (score 1):

In South Africa, we call them ***Stokvels***. Technically not English, but it has become a common word for English speakers in SA.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokvel

Comment: This is interesting, although I'm not sure why "stokvel" would be technically not English. The [Oxford dictionary lists it as an English word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stokvel) that originated `From an Africanized pronunciation of stock-fair`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're talking about a susu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susu_(informal_loan_club), and although I couldn't find that word in any English dictionaries, I can confirm that some people do just use that word in English, and some English speakers know what it means.

Comment: I've certainly never heard the word, I wouldn't expect many other native speakers to have, so it probably wouldn't be a good choice.

Answer (score -1):

***Pooling*** is a common one that others have already mentioned, but another one that I use a lot is the phrase ***pitching in***.

Example:

*Friend*: How are we going to manage the internet bill while we live together for the next year?

*Me*: I guess we'll all just have to **pitch in**.

Comment: *Pitching in* is common term, but it refers to everybody contributing money at once, not the establishment of a rotating fund.